# VS Team Services Web.config transformation for environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, azure-devops, web.config-transform

I am trying to setup production deployment with Team Services. I need to replace Dev configuration with Prod values. I want to apply Web.config XML transformation to achieve this. There is no documentation, only this little info bubble:

[image]

So I created `Web.<EnvironmentName - Matches TS env. name>.config`.

[image]

Guess what? This transformation doesn't work. Release logs thought say: `XML Transformations applied successfully`. `Web.Release.config transformation` - always work, regardless if XML transformation checkbox is checked or not. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's task you used? Which extension contains it? What's the detail build log?

Comment: You also could use Tokenization task. (https://github.com/openalm/Extension-UtilitiesPack/blob/master/Utilites/overview.md, https://dustinoprea.com/2016/05/06/using-tokenization-token-replacement-for-buildsreleases-in-tfs-2015/)

Comment: @starain-MSFT I used release definition variables instead. Though it's odd that Web.config transformations don't work as expected.

Comment: What's task used and what's the detail build log?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the "Web.environment.config" file is placed in the same path with "web.config" file. And then the task will apply the transformation like below:
[image]

Another thing is that, the "XML transformation" option is used to transform the original web.config file in your project. If you have both "Web.release.config" file and "Web.environment.config" file, it will apply the transformation with "Web.release.config" first, and then throw an error when apply the transformation with "Web.environment.config" file since the web.config is already been transformed.